# Read .gitlab-ci.yml variables from a file

Tags: environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I have been searching for ways to read a file with environment variables in GitLab CI/CD. Specifically they should be used in the `services` entry of a job.

```yaml
variables:
#  POSTGRES_USER: testuser
#  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testpw
#  POSTGRES_DB: testdb

test:
  image: python:3
  services:
    - name: postgis/postgis
```

I want to read the variables from a file stored in the same repository.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be achieved by the [`include`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#include) keyword:

```yaml
include: /test/postgis.yml
```

with `/test/postgis.yml` having these contents:

```yaml
variables:
  POSTGRES_USER: testuser
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testpw
  POSTGRES_DB: testdb
```